# how to get child params angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5, router

In my application the route is something like this:

```
{
  path: 'routeA/:paramA',
  component: ComponentA,
  children: [
    {
      path: 'routeB/:paramB',
      component: ChildComponentB,
      children: [
        {
          path: 'routeC/:paramC',
          component: ChildComponentC
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
},
```

I tried:

1:

```
const param = this.route.paramMap.subscribe(( params: ParamMap ) : void => {

  console.info(params)
```

2:

```
const params = this.route.firstChild.snapshot.params['codigo-pessoal']
        console.info(params)
```

Answer (score 2):

For componentA,

```
import {Router, ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component-a',
  templateUrl: './component-a.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./component-a.component.scss'],
});
export class ComponentA {
  paramA: any;
  constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute) {
     this.paramA = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['paramA'];
     // Or you can try this one also
     this.route.params.subscribe(res => this.paramA = res.paramA);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `ChildComponentC` inject `ActivatedRoute` as a dependency:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
```

Then, in `ngOnInit`, use this:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params.subscribe(params => console.log(params));
}
```